# Entered Germany with US passport but leaving Europe with EU passport, complications?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, switzerland, eu-citizens, german-citizens

I am a US/German dual citizen about to start studies in Switzerland in a month. Previously, I traveled in Europe for about 2 months on a US passport. While in Europe, I received a German passport. I plan to leave Switzerland in 6 months and travel back to the US. I am aware that US citizens are given only 3 months in the Schengen zone. Will this lead to any complications even if I leave on my German passport? Will either of my passports be affected?

Comment: "affected" in what way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an EU/EEA/Swiss citizen, you have a nearly absolute right to enter the Schengen area and as such you cannot be fined for "overstaying" on your US passport. You having this right is a property of you as an EU citizen and having a German passport is simply a way of demonstrating that fact.

Also note that Schengen border control officers routinely forget to stamp passports at exit immigration so there are tens of thousands of travellers out there with no proof of exiting the Schengen area. While this could be a problem for non-EU citizens, there is no reason for you to be concerned about this matter.

Comment: If you put *German citizen* (or citizen any of the Schengen member states, as e.g. also the non-EU states Switzerland or Norway) instead of *EU citizen*, you are correct and the right isn't *nearly absolute* but *absolute*. You could arrive without any papers floating on a tree and they'd have to let you in.

Comment: @Janka there are some limits to the freedom of movement that make it close to, but not absolute technically: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-does-european-union-freedom-of-movement-mean-and-how-much-can-individual

Comment: Romania is not a full member of the Schengen Zone.

Comment: @Janka yes but this question is about entering the Schengen area. Romanian citizens currently have the same rights to do so as German citizens.

Comment: I nitpick. The OP is a citizen of Germany, so why broadening the question to all EU member states (and leaving out the non-EU member states of the Schengen zone) and blurrying the sight?

Comment: @Janka the freedom of movement rules currently apply to all Schengen states. And I didn't mention anything about non-Schengen EU states.

Comment: @Janka Actually, mentioning EU citizenship is both accurate and useful as it might serve to dispel some confusion. On the other hand, focusing on citizens of the “Schengen member states” is inaccurate in several ways. The right to enter the Schengen area cover EU citizens as such and therefore fully apply to Romanian citizens without *any* restriction.

Comment: Conversely, being a citizen of another Schengen state confers no advantage whatsoever when entering another Schengen state compared to the rights enjoyed by EU citizens. These rights only apply to, e.g., Swiss or Norwegian citizens through separate association agreements. The fact that a state is in the Schengen area is irrelevant and unrelated to EU freedom of movement rules. See my [answer to the other question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-does-european-union-freedom-of-movement-mean-and-how-much-can-individual/4965#4965) for details and sources on this.

Comment: @Janka a German citizen may be excluded from Switzerland (for example) if he or she is a threat to public safety.  That is why the right to enter Schengen and EU countries other than Germany is *nearly absolute* rather than *absolute.*

Comment: @phoog: This is just the same within the Schengen Zone. Any country may exclude individual persons based on that claim of threatening public safety. It's often executed e.g. for football hooligans.

Comment: Schengen is about border controls. I am an EU citizen from a non Schengen country (Ireland) and have the same rights of freedom of movement as a Schengen national. These are two different things and whether you are from a Schengen country isn't material. There were limits on Romania and Bulgaria freedom of movement (and the other expansion countries before that) for a period but this again has nothing to do with Schengen which does not in itself confer any more or different freedom of movement rights.

Comment: @Janka "Any country may exclude individual persons based on that claim of threatening public safety": unless the person is a citizen of that country.  That's precisely the difference between "absolute" and "nearly absolute."  For example, if a bunch of football hooligans were identified for exclusion from Germany before a match, anyone in that group who was a German citizen would not be excludable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82384/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathanreez-entered-germany-with-us-passport-but-leavin).

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I can see regarding the passports is that the "trail of stamps" on your US passport shows you still in Schengen. This could irritate some third country visa officials, but not those from the Schengen zone (if you show them your German passport, old stamps are no issue).

- I presume that you got a fresh German passport, not a fresh citizenship, or the dual citizenship might be a problem.
- In the future it would be a good idea to use the German passport to enter the EU, fewer complications and questions that way.
- If you are worried that your German passport might expire at an inconvenient time in the future, you can apply for a German identity card even if you are not resident in Germany. It might be clever to get one in a few years, so that the validity periods of the passport and the identity card overlap -- if the passport is just expired the ID card is still valid, and vice versa. The ID card allows you to travel in the EU and some other countries. Of course that means going through the renewal twice that often, so YMMV.

Comment: How is applying for an ID card helpful in this particular situation?

Comment: @JonathanReez, hgund sounds as if he was a German citizen without a (valid) passport. Having both documents with different expiration dates helps to prevent that problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As a German citizen, you do of course have the right to enter, leave and stay in Germany as you please.

In practice, you shouldn't have problems using the German passport for the EU in the future.

<strike>However, you should assume that your US passport is "in the system", and will be marked as overstayed. Note that passports are usually electronically scanned at border crossings - wether or not you get an actual stamp.</strike> The Schengen does not have an electronic entrance/exit database (yet), though you still may be questioned if you miss the exit stamp.

You could also just go on a brief trip outside the Schengen to get the exit stamp, and re-enter on the German one.

Nevertheless it makes sense to use the German Passport any EU travel in the 
future, to avoid any misunderstandings (US law requires you to always use the US passport when going there).

For third countries, it makes obvious sense to always use the passport that is most convenient for the destination country...

If you're living abroad when your German passport expires, you can renew it at the German embassy.

**Disclaimer:** Nothing I say should be taken as professional legal advice. If you have doubts, ask a legal counsel. Especially true if you just naturalised; in this cases there arcane rules to retaining dual citizenship, which are beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. While one is currently being developed, there is still no “the system” recording entries and exits shared between Schengen countries. The entry might have been recorded in a national system but since it is perfectly legal and common to exit the Schengen area through another state, registering exits is not mandatory, and there is no system in place to share and match any such records between member state, it's impossible for the state that recorded the entry to mark a passport as “overstayed”. In 2008, enforcement still relies strictly on paper stamps.

Comment: @Relaxed did you mean to type "in 2018"?

Comment: You are apparently right, corrected.

Comment: @phoog Yes, sorry.